# How to extract character after second hyphen(-) using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking out to extract character after second hyphen from a column in a excel.

```
col1                                                 Col2

BEQ-REG NO 2547-DG225647 INR 287649499.75/GST
RCN-REG NO 0188-ST224536 INR 16784398.75/NPM
DSC-REG NO 0266-BC115677 INR 8757323.50/NS
PST-REG NO 2077-DG887536 INR 9432789.50/HR
DSC-REG NO 3066-DX256788 INR 556798/#
```

Expected Output

```
col1                                                 Col2
    
BEQ-REG NO 2547-DG225647 INR 287649499.75/GST      DG225647
RCN-REG NO 0188-ST224536 INR 16784398.75/NPM       ST224536
DSC-REG NO 0266-BC115677 INR 8757323.50/NS         BC115677
PST-REG NO 2077-DG887536 INR 9432789.50/HR         DG887536
DSC-REG NO 3066-DX256788 INR 556798/#              DX256788
```

Please suggest how i can extract values from col1 to col2

```
=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",2))+1,255))
```

Comment: These samples strings look like they follow an exact pattern which you could take advantage of with an extremely simple `MID()` formula.

Comment: If the positions of the `-` and the space are consistent (as your sample data  suggests), then use `=MID(A1,17,8)`

Comment: The `MID()` formula is probably the easiest solution but you could also use Column From Examples in Power Query. I believe you could also just start typing your desired outcome in an adjacent column and Excel will guess results for rows beneath your entered cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is always 8 characters long, you can use:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",2))+1,8)
```

If it is of variable length the following will work, assuming you want everything after the second "`-`" and the first space:

```
=LEFT(MID(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",2))+1,255),FIND(" ",MID(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",2))+1,255)))
```

Comment: According to the sample data it can get even much simpler. +

Answer (score 0):

Second dash to space:

```
 =LET(data, A2, i, FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(data,"-","#",2)), MID(data, i+1, FIND(" ",data,i)-i))
```